# "On top of" + verb, past action

Tags: grammar, conjugations

If I am referring to some point in the past, and want to mention that, at this point, John had done three things, which should I use:

"John had done this and that on top of having done this last thing."

or

"John had done this and that on top of doing this last thing."

Comment: Both are fine, and it's just a stylistic choice with no *semantic* significance. Note that unless it's important to your narrative context that John did all these things ***before*** something else in the past that you're primarily writing about, there's probably no good reason for using Past Perfect at all: *He did this and that, besides / on top of doing the other*.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do prefer the second one, which sounds less heavy, but was not sure that it was as correct as the first one. And yes, it is important that he did all these things before something else in the past. Thanks again!